# How to center align a small image with text in the center both horizontal and vertically?

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

I have a div where i'm trying to center align a text and a image both vertical as well horizontal.

So for horizontal i have given `text-align: center;` for vertical am lacking because the image size and the actual image is little bit different, it is a png format so you can see the transparent. There is extra space in the image so it might display in the top.

How to make both text and image same level as well center aligned. Any idea would be helpful

Here is the css  Edited after question asked

```
.click
{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;

}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqDu7/11/)
Does position absolute have an effect? Because in my local i can't align it as in fiddle answers

Comment: Yes it does, it forces display: block;
But you can just warp the element into another one and give the outer one the position: absolute; I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just handle the div as a table cell by setting the `display: table-cell;` value. Then you can use `vertical-align: middle;` to align the content.

**UPDATE:** For absolute positioning wrapp the div into an outer div and apply the position there.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="click">
        Thumbs up <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC5s4.png">
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
.click
{
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqDu7/12/)**

Comment: No, I just added more height to see the effect. And keep in mind that the percentage values refer to the parent elements dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Give the text and the image separately a **vertical-align: middle** style

Something like this:

```
<div class="click">
    <span class="valign">Thumbs up</span> 
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC5s4.png" class="valign"/>
</div>
```

And then:

```
.valign {    
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Test here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swuxm/)

Or alternative would be to set the container div to

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

And the the image to

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: First one itself working right. What is the advantage in alternative

Comment: No advantage for either of the solutions. Just a matter of personal preferences which you want to use. But the first solution includes an additional <span> around your text.

Comment: The the text in the div doesn't need a separate vertical-align: middle if the .click class has that style. Only the image needs it separatly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table-cell` for the div, and `vertical-align:middle` for content. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xqDu7/10/

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include it position:absolute; now am not getting it in center

Comment: No i already have this absolute position for that element.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.click
{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    width:220px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -110px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqDu7/9/

Comment: He wants the content of the div to be aligned not the div itself... ;-)